# How to integrate Siri with flutter application?

Tags: ios, flutter, siri

I want to integrate Siri in my flutter app for iOS. When the user asks a particular question,
Siri must get the output from the app and execute a function in the app. How can I achieve this?
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

In order to achieve this you will need the following:

1. Create your intent definition file in XCode
2. Add the Intents extension target to your Xcode project
3. Configure the Flutter extension home widget
   https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget
4. Add app groups capabilities to both your Runner target and the Intents target make sure to use the same group id
5. Initialize the App on the flutter side with the same group id
6. Save the data that your Siri intent would need using the home widget extension methods
7. Use the saved data reading from UserDefaults

There are some things to consider here:
Siri's intents are in a different Target because they can run in the background if needed, this is why you cannot have a direct communication line between the intent and flutter (Yet).
Instead what you will need to do is to save in memory some data your user might need when using Siri maybe a user id or API key, if you need to make some HTTP calls you will have to do it from Swift.

This is why we need the home widget extension since Home widgets also use a different target and This extension opens a communication channel using App groups and UserDefaults we could use the same communication channel to send data to our Siri Intent.

Just follow the configuration guide of the HomeWidget extension and add AppGroups capabilities to your runner Target and also to your Siri intent. make sure you use the same group ID in all of them including on the flutter side:

HomeWidget.setAppGroupId('YOUR_GROUP_ID');

Then you can use the extension methods to send and receive data between flutter and swift.

Comment: Hey, can you add a sample code?

Comment: @Andres Sosa martinex , thanks for answer, can you please link any code snippet or project that shows a demo of this ?